# Advantages of using *args in python instead of passing a list as a parameter

Tags: python

I'm going through python and I was wondering what are the advantages of using the *args as a parameter over just passing a list as a parameter, besides aesthetics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally it's used to either pass a list of arguments to a function that would normally take a fixed number of arguments, or in function definitions to allow a variable number of arguments to be passed in the style of normal arguments. For instance, the `print()` function uses varargs so that you can do things like `print(a,b,c)`.

One example from a recent SO question: you can use it to pass a list of `range()` result lists to `itertools.product()` without having to know the length of the list-of-lists.

Sure, you could write every library function to look like this:

```
def libfunc1(arglist):
    arg1 = arglist[1]
    arg2 = arglist[2]
    ...
```

...but that defeats the point of having named positional argument variables, it's basically exactly what `*args` does for you, and it results in redundant braces/parens, since you'd have to call a function like this:

```
libfunc1([arg1val,arg2val,...])
```

...which looks very similar to...

```
libfunc1(arg1val,arg2val,...)
```

...except with unnecessary characters, as opposed to using `*args`.

Comment: Thanks, however I was asking what are the advantages of this over passing a list as a parameter. obviously the designers of python preferred this for some reason, since besides aesthetics, this method is seemingly totally redundant.

Comment: Added an example. One of the biggies is that it allows you to pass varying-length things to standard library functions easily, without the library functions having to be rewritten.

Comment: Could you explain how would you "pass a list of arguments to a function that would normally take a fixed number of arguments" using *args ? Example of function which takes a fixed number of arguments: fn(arg1). arg1 could be, for instance, a string. If *args was used instead of arg1, the method creator would already allow the method to take a variable number of arguments since its creation and using a list instead of *args would bring the same result.

Answer (score 2):

That is for **flexibility**.

It allows you to pass on the arguments, without knowing how much you need. A typical example:

```
def f(some, args, here): # <- this function might accept a varying nb of args
    ...

def run_f(args, *f_args):
    do_something(args)
    # run f with whatever arguments were given:
    f(*f_args)
```

Make sure to check out the `**` keyword version.